# Creating a new list of "n" alternating elements from a list

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an unknown value of x. Say I have the following array:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Say x = 2, I want 2 arrays arranged so that it becomes:

```
array2 = [ [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10] , [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11] ]
```

If x = 3, then I want 3 arrays arranged as such:

```
array3 = [ [0, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11] ]
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you run into an issue?

Comment: You may be looking for the modulo operator `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that does not require itertools:

```
def split_array (arr, parts):
    result = []
    for i in range(parts):
        result.append([])
        for j in range(0,len(arr),parts):
            if i+j < len(arr):
                result[i].append(arr[i+j])
    return result

array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

print(split_array(array,2))
#[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]]

print(split_array(array,3))
#[[0, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11]]
```